# Remove reference in decltype (return T instead of T& where T& is the decltype)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-deduction

(If you're a C++11 pro, skip to the bold paragraph.)

Let's say I want to write a template method which calls and returns the result of a passed object which type is the template parameter:

```
template<ReturnType, T>
ReturnType doSomething(const T & foo) {
    return foo.bar(); // EDIT: Might also be an expression introducing a temp val
}
```

So `T` has to have a method `ReturnType T::bar() const` in order to be used in a call like this:

```
struct MyClass {
    ...
    int bar() const;
    ...
};
...
MyClass object;
int x = doSomething<int, MyClass>(object);
```

We don't have to write `MyClass` thanks to type deduction and the call becomes:

```
int x = doSomething<int>(object);
```

But omitting `<int>` too results in a compilation error because the method doesn't require to return int in order to be assigned to `x` afterwards (it could return `char` for example).

In C++0x/11 we have the `auto` and `decltype` with which we can use to deduce the return type of a template method:

```
template<T>
auto doSomething(const T & foo) -> decltype(foo.bar()) {
    return foo.bar(); // EDIT: Might also be an expression introducing a temp val
}
```

The compiler will now find out what the type of `foo.bar()` is and just uses this as the return type. With our concrete class `MyClass` this will be an `int` and the following would suffice:

```
int x = doSomething(object);
```

**Now to my question:**

If MyClass defines `bar()` as returning an `int&`, the return type of `doSomething(object)` will also be an `int&` = `decltype(foo.bar())`. This is a problem, since as G++ now complies that I'm *returning reference to temporary*.

How can I fix this? Is there something like `remove_reference` which can be used like `remove_reference(decltype(foo.bar()))`?

I thought about just declaring a helper method which takes a `T&` and returns a `T` and then define the return type of `doSomething` to be `decltype(helper(foo.bar()))`. But there has to be a better way, I'm feeling it.

Comment: How is this a problem? All you'd be doing is passing on the reference. And yes, there's `std::remove_reference<T>::type`.

Comment: @GManNickG I don't want a warning in my program. I want to compile with `-Werror -Wall`. Thanks for the `std::remove_reference` hint, I knew I had seen this before but couldn't find it on google when searching for "c++11 template type deduction remove reference", maybe my search was too localized :)

Comment: No, I'm saying there shouldn't be a warning at all. If `foo.bar()` returns a reference, you should be able to return that just fine as a reference as well.

Comment: Ah yeah, in this case. `foo.bar()` was a bad example, let's say `return foo.bar() + 1`. In my case I'm working with iterators and want to deduce `T` of a provided container type which has `begin()`, so my decltype is `decltype(*container.begin())` which is a `T&`. Since I return a temporary `T` I needed to remove the reference.

Comment: By the way, any conforming container should have an inner typedef `value_type`, allowing you to just specify `typename Container::value_type` as the return type. (Though perhaps your function should accept iterators instead of the container directly, in which as your return value would be `typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type`.)

Comment: @GManNickG In fact I'm not working on containers directly but on iterator pairs (as one single type) which also has `begin()` and `end()` but no `value_type` because I want the best flexibility I can get. (Maybe this is a bit silly...)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

To remove a reference:

```
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_same<int, std::remove_reference<int&>::type>::value, "wat");
```

In your case:

```
template <typename T>
auto doSomething(const T& foo)
    -> typename std::remove_reference<decltype(foo.bar())>::type
{
    return foo.bar();
}
```

---

Just to be clear, note that as written returning a reference is just fine:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct f
{
    int& bar() const
    {
        static int i = 0;
        return i;
    } 
};

template <typename T>
auto doSomething(const T& foo)
    -> decltype(foo.bar())
{ 
    return foo.bar();
}

int main()
{
    f x;
    return doSomething(x);
}
```

The returned reference can simply be passed on without error. Your example in the comment is where it becomes important and useful:

```
template <typename T>
auto doSomething(const T& foo)
    -> decltype(foo.bar())
{ 
    return foo.bar() + 1; // oops
}
```

Comment: In C++14, you can also use `std::remove_reference_t<int&>`.

Comment: @Kupiakos In C++14 you can use an auto return type without a trailing decltype.

Comment: @AlyssaHaroldsen I can't find much documentation on `std::remove_reference_t`. How is this different from `std::remove_reference` ?

Comment: `std::remove_reference_t` is equivalent to `std::remove_reference::type`. That is a shorthand way of writing it, it is similar to `std::remove_reference_v` where `_v` denotes `::value`.