# Generally, is dereference pointer expression results a reference type?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, reference, dereference

Deferencing pointer leads to using the value of the object indirectly. But I've never really understood what does the "using" means. I started to think the question until my compiler yield an error for the following code

```
int i = 0, *pi = &i;
decltype(*pi) c; // error: 'c' declared as reference but not initialized.
```

I looked at the error for a very long time and searched some questions I can only give out the following arguments. I don't know if they are correct or not.

**Arguments 1:**

1) `*p` is an expression that is not a variable (or non-variable expression)

2) dereferencing pointer expression yields a reference, we are in fact using a reference to access the value of the object

**Arguments 2:**

the dereferencing expression only for which `decltype` returns a reference, it is not a general case

Please points out any incorrectness or inaccurate descriptions of the above arguments.

Comment: Here's a technique that can almost always be used to get the compiler to tell you the type of an expression: https://wandbox.org/permlink/GBApa0x01iwP7K9a (try to access a non-existent member)

Comment: Seems to me to be an excellent opportunity to dig into [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4700.pdf) for an answer (you might learn another thing or two as well while browsing through it).

Comment: Related voodoo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202289/remove-reference-in-decltype-return-t-instead-of-t-where-t-is-the-decltype

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Dereferencing a pointer yields an lvalue expression of the pointed-to type designating the object or function pointed to.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.unary.op#1) It does not yield a reference.<sup>*</sup> `*pi` is an lvalue of type `int`.

`decltype` (with an exception not relevant here) reports both an expression's *type* and its *value category*, [the latter being encoded with reference types](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.type.simple#4). Since `*pi` is an lvalue, it's encoded as an lvalue reference type, so `decltype(*pi)` is `int &`: `int` for the type, `&` for the value category.

Expressions never have reference type because any referenceness is adjusted away ["prior to any further analysis"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.type#1).

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> This isn't a merely technical distinction: per the direction of [core issue 232](https://wg21.link/cwg232) and [core issue 453](https://wg21.link/cwg453), there are valid dereference expressions you can write where binding its result to a reference would cause undefined behavior.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

To answer your title question: as T.C. answered too, no. Expressions never have reference type. Given an `int a; int &b = a;`, both the expression `a` and the expression `b` have type `int`, and both expressions are lvalues.

> 1) `*p` is an expression that is not a variable (or non-variable expression)

Correct.

> 2) dereferencing pointer expression yields a reference, we are in fact using a reference to access the value of the object

Dereferencing a pointer gives an lvalue, which `decltype` changes into an lvalue reference.

> the dereferencing expression only for which decltype returns a reference, it is not a general case

I'm not entirely sure what you mean here. If you mean that when `decltype` doesn't produce a reference, having a declaration `decltype(...) c;` without an initialiser can be valid, then yes, indeed. If you mean that aside from dereferenced pointers, `decltype` never produces a reference type, then no. For instance,

```
int a;
decltype((a)) b; // not okay - decltype((a)) is int & because (a) is not the name of the
                 // variable, and the expression (a) is an lvalue
decltype(a) c;   // okay - decltype(a) is int because a is the name of the variable
decltype(+a) d;  // okay - decltype(+a) is int because the +a is a prvalue of type int
```

Answer (score 3):

As a matter of fact, standard says following in 8.5.2.1:

> The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it
>   is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a
>   function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or
>   function to which the expression points. If the type of the expression
>   is “pointer to T”, the type of the result is “T”.

So it is not the reference, but `decltype()` gives you something which actually has a representation in the C++ types system, and reference is the closest thing to it.