# 'this' in C++ is a pointer to a reference?

Tags: c++, this-pointer

I know this is silly and the title probably isn't the answer.. 
I always thought of `this` as a pointer to the current object which is supplied in every method call from an object (which is not a static method)

but looking at what my code actually returns for example:

```
Test& Test::func () 
{ 
   // Some processing 
   return *this; 
}
```

the dereference of `this` is returned... and the return type is a reference to the object.... so what does that make `this`? Is there something under the hood I'm not understanding well?

Comment: Far too much: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48388510/generally-is-dereference-pointer-expression-results-a-reference-type

Comment: `this` in C++ is a pointer to the object instance itself. Dereferencing it yields the object. Returning the object by reference forms a reference (alias) to the object and that is what is returned.

Comment: Side note: You can't do a pointer to a reference. A reference is just another name for an existing object so there is nothing to point at. Take the address of a reference and you get the address of the referenced object.

Comment: References were added to C++ later on.  Otherwise we'd probably have `self` reference, that is a `Test&`.  But by the time references were added, that shipped had sailed, and `this` was firmly entrenched and relied upon by dozens, if not hundreds, of users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that a reference is simply *a different name* for an object.

That implies that returning a reference is the same thing as returning an object on type level of abstraction; it is *not* the same thing in the result: returning a reference means the caller gets a reference to the *current* object, whereas returning an object gives him (a reference to) a *copy* of the current object - with all the consequences, like the copy constructor being called, deep copy decisions are being made, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this):

> The keyword this is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object, on which the member function is being called.

And then (perhaps easier to grasp):

> The type of this in a member function of class X is X* (pointer to X). If the member function is cv-qualified, the type of this is cv X* (pointer to identically cv-qualified X). Since constructors and destructors cannot be cv-qualified, the type of this in them is always X*, even when constructing or destroying a const object.

So, `this` is not a pointer to a reference, but just a pointer.

Actually you cannot have a pointer to a reference, because taking the address of a reference will give you the address of referenced object.

Further, there is no special syntax in C++ to form a reference. Instead references have to be bound on initialization, for example:

```
int x = 3;
int& y = x;   // x is int, but y is int&
assert( &y == &x); // address of y is the address of x
```

Similar when returning a reference from a function:

```
int& get_x() {
    static int x = 3;
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply:

```
test t1;  //  t1 is a test object.

test& t2 = t1; //  t2 is another name for t1.

test* t3; //  t3 holds an address of a test object.

*t3; //  derefernce t. which gives you, the test object that t3 points to.
```

`this` is a pointer to the current test object.
therefore `*this` is the current test object, and because the return value type is `test&`, when you call the function, you get the same object you called the function from.