# c++ why decltype(*pointer) yields a reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, language-lawyer, decltype

I wanted to know why, when I use `decltype (* pointer)`, it defines the type of the variable as a reference.  For example:

```
int i = 42, * p = & i;
decltype (* p) c = i;
```

Now `c` is a reference (linked to `i`).  Why is it a reference and not an integer? I'm reading the book Cpp Primer 5th. Edition.  P. 110 says this and I do not understand why.

Comment: Because the dereference operator is defined to return a `T&`. That's C++. Use `std::remove_reference_t` if you want to remove the reference.

Comment: More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202289/remove-reference-in-decltype-return-t-instead-of-t-where-t-is-the-decltype

Comment: @DeiDei Thank you! For me it did not make sense for a pointer to return a reference, I was lost, but in the book says this, I'm reading here, thanks!

Comment: Try `decltype(+*p)`.

Comment: @DeiDei There is no such thing as an operator "defined to return a T&".

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Actually, `*p` has type `int` (in C/C++). No expression has type `int&` in C++.

Comment: @curiousguy I'm very surprised by that, but it seems you're right. It's unfortunate because it seems much easier to understand and explain if you treat it as a reference. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Don't forget that the origin of the concepts of the type system is a **copy-paste of C types** where there is no such thing. But the intuition of a lvalue having reference type is *seducing*. (And I admit that I had been seduced by this notion.)

Comment: If you were creating a brand new C++ like language, what would you do? (The question I always ask whenever a design is found to be contrary to intuition.) (D&E (Stroustrup) describes sound design principles for programming languages.) So do all lvalues now have reference type? This is _not_ necessarily intuitive and easy to teach: `int i;` declares an object `i` but expression `i` would now have type `int&` although no `&` declarator exists.

Comment: @curiousguy The mental model I had was that only an object which was declared as type `T` would be type `T`. So for `int i;`, the type of `i` is `int`. But anything else that would refer to `i` by any other name would be `int &`. It seemed elegant to me but I bet there are details that would make such a model impractical.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Contrary to apparently popular belief, `*p` has type `int`. From [[expr.unary.op]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.unary.op#1)

> The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points. If the type of the expression is “pointer to T”, **the type of the result is “T”**.

The reason `decltype(*p)` yields `int&` is because of how `decltype` works. From [[dcl.type.simple]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.type.simple#4)

> For an expression e, the type denoted by decltype(e) is defined as follows: [...]
>
> - otherwise, if e is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access, decltype(e) is the type of the entity named by e. If there is no such entity, or if e names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
> - otherwise, if e is an xvalue, decltype(e) is T&&, where T is the type of e;
> - otherwise, if e is an lvalue, decltype(e) is T&, where T is the type of e; [...]

Here id-expression means an expression exactly consisting of a possibly parenthesized name.

Since `*p` is an lvalue expression of type `int` and not an unparenthesized id-expression nor class member access, the third bullet applies and `decltype(*p)` is `int&`.

It is worthy to note `i` is an unparenthesized id-expression, therefore the first bullet applies and `decltype(i)` is `int`.

Comment: "_Contrary to apparently popular belief, *p has type int._" not just a pointer dereference, all C++ expressions that are "popularly believed" to have type `int&` actually have type `int`; just like in C (well the value categories are slightly different in modern C++, but the principle is the same)

Answer (score 5):

The type that `decltype(expr)` will give you depends on the [value category](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) of the expression. If `expr` is not just an *id-expression* (i.e. directly the name of a thing), then the rules basically are:

- If `expr` is an xvalue of type `T`, then `decltype(expr)` will be
  `T&&`.
- If `expr` is an lvalue of type `T`, then `decltype(expr)` will
  be `T&`.
- Otherwise, `decltype(expr)` will be `T`.

In your case, `*p` is an lvalue of type `int`. Thus `decltype(*p)` is defined to be `int&`. If you want `decltype` to give you `int`, you'll have to make the expression be a prvalue, for example by applying the unary + operator like suggested by @Cheers and hth. - Alf in his comment above. However, such arcane constructions might better be avoided in real code. For the sake of readability it might be better to just use `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*p)>`.

Comment: IOW, `decltype` is not the declared **type** of that expression. It's the type decorated with the value category. Terrible keyword choice!