# int a=3; int *p=&a; decltype (a) k1; decltype (*p) k2; k1 is int type and k2 is int& type why?

Tags: c++, reference, decltype, rvalue, lvalue

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a=3;
    int *p=&a;

    decltype (a) k1;
    decltype (*p) k2;
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Declaration of reference variable 'k2' requires an initializer
```

Explanation given to such phenomena is " `decltype` returns a reference type for expression that yield objects that can stand on the LHS of the assignment"

see what `*p` yields value of of the object it points means `3` and what `a` yields value of itself which is  `3`.

Now we talk manipulatively that `*p` refers to object `a` then `a` also refers to `a` itself.

So I am not digesting the explanation given for such phenomena.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ why decltype(\*pointer) yields a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388753/c-why-decltypepointer-yields-a-reference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` is an unparenthesised id expression.

`*p` is not an id expression. It is an indirection operation.

`decltype` behaves differently when the operand is an unparenthesised id expression than when the operand is not an unparenthesised id expression.

`decltype` of an unparenthesised id expression doesn't yield a reference type but rather the type of the entity named by the id expression. The type of the entity named by `a` is `int`.

`decltype` of a non-unparenthesised-id-expression may yield either an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference or a non-reference depending on the value category of the expression. `*p` is an lvalue expression, so `decltype (*p)` yields an lvalue reference i.e. `int&`.

> see what *p yields value of of the object it points means 3 and what a yields value of itself which is 3.

There is no difference between the expressions `a` and `*p` in regards to what the expressions themselves yield. They are both lvalue expressions of the same type and name the same object.

The distinction is that one is an unparenthesised id-expression and thus applies for the exceptional case of `decltype` while the other is not.

Comment: And so `decltype ((a)) k3; /*int& k3;*/`.

Comment: @eerorika **1.** So how to categorize that one expression is unparenthesised id expression or not ? **2.** and also what is exactly meant by unparenthesised id expression ? **3.**  Regarding `yield either an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference or a non-reference` here non-reference means you are talking about `rvalue` right ?

Comment: @Tylerdurden 1. An id-expression is either an unqualified-id or a qualified-id. 2. If there are no paretheses around it, then it's unparenthesised. Example: `a` is unparenthesised. `(a)` is parenthesised. 3. rvalue is a value category. I'm talking about the type. Non reference types area all types that are not references. Examples of such types are pointers, arithmetic types, class types, function types etc.

Comment: @eerorika can you please tell what is an id-expression ? Really I looked but can't find. There is question on stakoverflow too but I couldn't get it. If you provide link that's okay too.

Comment: @Tylerdurden I already told you. An id-expression is either an unqualified-id or a qualified-id.

Comment: @eerorika can you elaborate please. what is unqualified-id or a qualified-id and also possible then elaborate id-expression.  and is id representing identifier here ? int, float , char are identifiers right ? are also they id expressions ?

Comment: @Tylerdurden `what is unqualified-id` unqualified-id is either identifier, operator-function-id, conversion-function-id, literal-operator-id, ~type-name, ~decltype-specifier or template-id. `or a qualified-id` qualified-id is nested-name-specifier optionally followed by template followed by unqualified-id. `is id representing identifier here ?` I believe id is related to identifier, yes. `int, float , char are identifiers right ?` Not right. Those are not identifiers, but *type-id*s. And furthermore, they aren't id-expressions.  `a` is an identifier and is thus an id-expression.

Comment: @eerorika can you give more examples of expressions which are not id-expression ?

Comment: @Tylerdurden Literals, `this`,  operator expressions, lambdas, folds, casts, yields, throws for example.

Comment: @eerorika  **1.**  `decltype((3)) k1;` not yielding rvalue-reference why ?  **2.**  `int a=3; int *p=&a;`   `decltype((p)) k2;` what's the type of k2 ? you said that `non-reference type` .  you said non references typs are `pointers`, `Arithmetic types` means int, char, float ? if yes how decltype is going to yield `int` as `decltype((3)) k1;`  yields rvalue( I feel it should return rvalue reference so I am assuming might be I am wrong I  don't know)  **3.**  `class types` for example class A{ } then type is `A` right ? 4. function types  `void fun(int, int)` what's the type of this function ?

Comment: @Tylerdurden 1. Because 3 is a prvalue and thus decltype yields non-reference. 2. It would be `int*&`, but you cannot default initialise references so it's ill-formed. Pointer types are not references. Reference types are not pointers. Yes, those are examples of arithmetic types. 3. Yes, `A` would be a class type. 4. `void(int,int)`

Answer (score 0):

Reference in its essence is not so different from a pointer. They are both referring to the object in memory. But I believe you already know that.
The thing with [decltype](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) is that it returns reference in this case. As pointed out in another answer here and mentioned [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category),
`*p` is the built-in indirection expression which is an lvalue. So decltype does this:

> b) if the value category of expression is lvalue, then decltype yields T&;

You can also verify this:

```cpp
std::cout << "*p and int are the same type? " << std::boolalpha
          << std::is_same_v<decltype(*p), int> << '\n'
          << "*p and int& are the same type? " 
          << std::is_same_v<decltype(*p), int&> << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) for

```
decltype ( expression )
```

> If the argument is any other expression of type T, and  if the value category of expression is lvalue, then decltype yields T&;

So now lets look at your example. In particular, we have :

```
decltype (*p) k2;
```

The "thing" inside the parenthesis `()` is an expression. That is, `*p` is an expression. Now there are two important thing:

1. The type of this expression is `int`.
2. The value category of this expression is an **lvalue**.

And so according to the above quoted statement, the result will be T& or `int&` in our case.

And since we must always initialize a reference, so you get the said error.