# Why std::is_integral returns false for decltype(*t) where t is int*?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, c++-templates

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int* t;
  using T = decltype(*t);
  cout << is_integral<T>::value << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Why does the code above print 0?

Comment: Here's a handy trick for you. Declare but not define `template<typename> struct PrintTypeInErr;` - then try creating a temporary object `PrintTypeInErr<T>{};` - the compiler error message will include what `T` really is, so you can debug yourself.

Comment: ^ Alternatively, make a template function that prints `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` (or `__FUNCSIG__` on MSVC). This will print the template argument type, among other things.

Comment: Dupe: [c++ why decltype(*pointer) yields a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388753/c-why-decltypepointer-yields-a-reference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*t` is an [lvalue expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue), then [`decltype(*t)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) leads to a reference type as `int&`.

> b) if the value category of expression is lvalue, then decltype yields `T&`;

You might use [`std::remove_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) to get the result you expected. E.g.

```
is_integral<remove_reference_t<T>>::value
```

[LIVE](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/n76o1sWqf)